# Using new github tokens to list and create comments on pull requests

Tags: github, github-api

After I switched to the new Github Token format, I am not able anymore to perform a call for this github API:

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/issues/comments#list-issue-comments

My script does the following:

```sh
[[ -z "$GITHUB_REPO_SLUG" ]] && export GITHUB_REPO_SLUG="$TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG"
GITHUB_API_BASE_URL="https://api.github.com/repos/${GITHUB_REPO_SLUG}"
GITHUB_AUTH_HEADER="Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN"

comment_ids=$(curl -s -H "$GITHUB_AUTH_HEADER" "$GITHUB_API_BASE_URL/issues/$pull_request_id/comments" \
        | jq --arg USER "$GITHUB_USER" -r '. | map(select(.user.login==$USER)) | map(.id) | .[]')

for comment_id in $(echo $comment_ids); do
        jq -n -r --arg message "$message" '{ body: $message }' \
            | curl -s -H "$GITHUB_AUTH_HEADER" "$GITHUB_API_BASE_URL/issues/comments/$comment_id" -X PATCH --data @- > /dev/null
        echo "Edited comment with id $comment_id of PR $pull_request_id"
done
```

The api call that list comments ids responds:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/issues#list-issue-comments"
}
```

This still works using tokens in the old format, but doesn't with tokens in the new format.

Is there any way to use the GHP to call that api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The github user associated with the github token must be provided writing access to the repository.

Since this was missing API responded 404 (default behaviour set for Github APIs).